# Django Reversion

Tags: python, django, django-reversion

I want to undo my last POST/PUt/DELETE or any sort of transaction within a database. I read about [Django-reversion](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#reverting-to-previous-revisions) & tried implementing it. But to no luck. Here's my code. Please confirm what wrong am I doing!!!

Models to be reversed :-

```
@reversion.register
class Shipment(models.Model):
    job_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, db_index = True)

@reversion.register
class ShipmentScanMapping(models.Model):
    arm_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    reference_number = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    shipment = models.ForeignKey('Shipment',related_name ='scans')
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True)
```

Views

```
@csrf_exempt
@reversion.create_revision()
def db_commit(request):

    arm_id = scan_status = barcode = reference_number = customer_name = job_id = 12
    if request.is_ajax():
        shipment_obj = Shipment(job_id = job_id)
        shipment_obj.save()

        ShipmentScanMapping.objects.create(arm_id = arm_id,status = scan_status,barcode = barcode,reference_number = reference_number,
                                                customer_name = customer_name ,shipment= shipment_obj)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps('Success'), content_type = "application/json")        

@csrf_exempt
def db_undo(request):
    job_id = 12 # just for demo purpose
    shipment_obj = Shipment.objects.filter(job_id = job_id).order_by('-time')[0]

    your_model = ShipmentScanMapping.objects.get(shipment = shipment_obj)
    version_list = reversion.get_unique_for_object(your_model)[0]
    #version_data = version_list.field_dict
    #print version_data
    version_list.revert()

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps('Success'), content_type = "application/json")
```

**What wrong am I doing ??**

Answer (score 1):

In your example you just create new object. In this case `django-reversion` create initial state reversion for this object, but `django-reversion` allows you to roll back to the state of any previous revision. So modify your `ShipmentScanMapping` object and try again.

### Update

#### Initialize data:

```
>>> import reversion
>>> with reversion.create_revision():
...     shipment_obj = Shipment(job_id = 12)
...     shipment_obj.save()
...
>>> reversion.get_unique_for_object(shipment_obj)
[<Version: Shipment object>]
>>> with reversion.create_revision():
...     your_model = ShipmentScanMapping.objects.create(arm_id = 12,status = 12,barcode = 12,reference_number = 12,customer_name =12,shipment=shipment_obj)
...
>>> reversion.get_unique_for_object(your_model)
[<Version: ShipmentScanMapping object>]
>>> your_model.arm_id
12
>>> your_model.id
1
```

#### Update data:

```
>>> with reversion.create_revision():
...     your_model.arm_id=15
...     your_model.save()
...
>>> reversion.get_unique_for_object(your_model)
[<Version: ShipmentScanMapping object>, <Version: ShipmentScanMapping object>]
>>> ShipmentScanMapping.objects.get(id=1).arm_id
15
>>> [r.field_dict.get('arm_id') for r in reversion.get_unique_for_object(your_model)]
[u'15', u'12']
```

#### Revert:

```
>>> rev = reversion.get_unique_for_object(your_model)[-1]
>>> rev.field_dict.get('arm_id')
u'12'
>>> rev.revert()
>>> ShipmentScanMapping.objects.get(id=1).arm_id
```

### Update2

> Can I revert only those changes which have been updated(PUT) or any
>   POST/DELETE request can also be revert?

You can also recover a deleted object, see [docs](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#recovering-deleted-objects).

> How can I revert upto nth level?? Does [-1] means the DB will be
>   reverted to the latest update?

`get_unique_for_object` method returns a list of all previous versions, latest versions first. So you can select as usual selection from the list in python. By the way you can find the most recent version for a given date:

```
rev = reversion.get_for_date(your_model, datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 10))
```

### Update3

> if initially, the value was 3 and was updated with 12 and then
>   reverted back to 3. What happens with the value 12?? Also, how would I
>   revert back an insert(POST) query, eg:- if I inserted 12 and then I
>   want to revert this change?

Okay, let's consider how it works. When you register your model, the `django-reversion` begins to watch `post_save` signals from the model. Whenever you save changes to a model, it is serialized using the Django serialization framework into a JSON string and save it to the database as a `reversion.models.Version` model.

So when you need reverting some version, `django-reversion` load the appropriate Version model from the database, deserializing the model data, and re-saving the old data. During the re-saving the current state will be lost if not called method save. If it was called, the state will be stored in appropriate version(see text above).

If you need revert just created object, you should remove it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge shared. Can you please provide a sample code-snippet for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I've some doubts. `1)`Can I revert only  those changes which have been updated(PUT) or any POST/DELETE request can also be revert? `2)` How can I revert upto nth level?? Does `[-1]` means the DB will be reverted to the latest update? `3)` What happends to the new values which have been reverted by the old values?? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user1162512 Can you explain 3?

Comment: Thanks for the input Alex. By point 3, I mean what happens when to the new values, for eg:- if initially, the value was 3 and was updated with  12 and then reverted back to 3.  What happens with the value `12`?? Also, how would I revert back an insert(POST) query, eg:- if I inserted 12 and then I want to revert this change?

Comment: Thanks for the update and explanation. I tried your code. It works only for the first undo. If I keep undoing it, it still saves to the last entry I saved. In short, how do I implement multiple undo's ? Please share some knowledge on it.